# Remove Border In Tab Control VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, tabcontrol

I have a problem that is quite disturbing, in my control tab at the border there is a tab panel, this is very disturbing scene.

Problem Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1NO0.jpg

Please help me to remove the border that I put a red arrow

Comment: Set the border style to 'flat' instead of '3D' (I think).

Comment: The visual style renderer for TabControl is very buggy.  The .NET programmer had to do something about it, you can see his work [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabPage.cs,d46e10d3196b6f08), starting with "HACK".  That hack no longer works.  The odds that you are going to like the workarounds are zero, punt this problem by making the background colors the same.

Answer (score 1):

Set TabControl's `Margin` and `Padding` to 0, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Then this link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705698/remove-edit-tabcontrol-padding-for-tabpages

Comment: You can convert C# to vb.net. http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: do you have any tutorial ? its so hard for me :'(