# Vb.net how to remove tabcontrol border?

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

In my form, I'm using a tabcontrol. . I wish to remove these border https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BnmE.png and have an appearance like https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7jEB.png.

Any idea how it can be acieved ?

Regards!

Comment: [Remove/Edit TabControl Padding for TabPages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717038/7444103). Note that you don't need to inherit `NativeWindow` using a custom class. You just need to override WndProc of a custom control derived from TabControl (so you can also make other adjustments, if needed).

Comment: The correct measures (that answer hard-codes them) can be retrieved (to test how these offsets work) with SendMessage and [TCM_ADJUSTRECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tcm-adjustrect) with `wParam` set to `IntPtr.Zero`: it will return the RECT structure that defines the TabControl's current offsets. Note that you cannot use SendMessage with `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` from your own control while you have overridden WndProc to modify that same message: you'll get your own answer or a stack overflow. It's for testing on the standard control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the control contained on the tab page? It might have a **Margin** set. The default for the Margin (see the properties page) is 3 on all sides (`3,3,3,3`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

In the design window of your form, right click and look for properties.

After the properties window is opened, look for **BorderStyle** in **Appearance** section.
There you select **None** for **BorderStyle**.

Comment: Did you check in the program, any where programmatically they are setting the border style. If so set there None